# Timeout::Error on capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bdd, capybara

I have following gems in my `Gemfile`

```
gem 'steak'
gem 'capybara', '~>0.4.1'
```

When I run a test for single file there seems to be no problem however, if I run all the tests at once, I am getting `Timeout::Error`. Before timing out, the test hangs so I manually clicked a button and the error was `Element not found in the cache`. Is this some caching problem? I am also getting `Selenium::WebDriver::Element#value is deprecated, please use Selenium::WebDriver::Element#attribute('value')` warning when I run some of the tests.  I hope the question is clear, if anything is required for answering please let me know.

Note: I had set up steak through [steak-because-cucumber-is-for-vegerarians](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/steak-because-cucumber-is-for-vegetarians/)

Answer (score 1):

yeah I found this, seems like selenium does not support firefox 4. [seleniumhq.org](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.html#supported-browsers) I really hope this issue gets solved soon...